# how to get multiple values from multiple href

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

Hello I am using bootstrap and this code dont work I dont know whats the different from echo butmy code is like this

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="update_appointment.php<?php echo '?f=' . $txn_id . 'id=' . $f . 'l=' . $l .'m=' . $m .'mn=' . $mn .'ptn=' . $ptn .'sn=' . $sn .'bi=' . $bi .'ui=' . $ui .'a=' . $a .'d=' . $d .'cn=' . $cn; ?>" ><i class="icon-check"></i>&nbsp;Yes</a>
```

if I enter the button to echo, the button doesnt show? please help me

Comment: so we need more than the button, if the button's not showing we need to figure out why it's not showing, not what the button is.

Comment: Please post the HTML output you're seeing.